# How to reserve registered service usage with passing params in constructor?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, dryioc

I am a newbie to OOP and IOC container. I need to understand how to use depency injection. My app's simple structure is as below.

The code below belongs to CacheService:

```
using Akavache;

    public class CacheService : ICacheService
    {
        protected IBlobCache Cache;

        public CacheService(IBlobCache blobCache, string applicationName)
        {
            Cache = blobCache;
            BlobCache.ApplicationName = applicationName;
        }
    }
```

I have registered this service as below in App.cs Because I need to use the same service with 2 different types.

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IMockApiService, MockApiService>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IEssentialsService, EssentialsService>();

    containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<CacheService>(new CacheService(BlobCache.LocalMachine, "MyAppName"), "LocalMachineCache");
    containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<CacheService>(new CacheService(BlobCache.UserAccount, "MyAppName"), "UserAccountCache");
}
```

My ViewModel code is as below:

```
public class SettingsPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    protected ICacheService CacheService { get; private set; }

    public SettingsPageViewModel(ICacheService cacheService)
    {
        CacheService = cacheService;
    }
}
```

Is above usage possible or not? If it is possible how should I modify my structure? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this usage is *not* possible because your IoC container would not know how to resolve `ICacheService`, since you registered the instances as `CacheService`. When *DryIoc* tries to resolve `SettingsPageViewModel` it would encounter `ICacheService` and find the type not being registered. At least this is how the *Unity* container behaves.

Anyway, even *if* you registered `"LocalMachineCache"` and `"UserAccountCache"` as `ICacheService` I doubt that it'd work, since there would be no way to know for DryIoc which one shall be used with `SettingsPageViewModel`, hence you'd have to define which one to resolve.

According to its documentation, Prism resolves dependencies by the respective parameter name (unless I did not misunderstand this, [see here](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dependency-injection/registering-types.html#understanding-named-services)). Assuming that you need the local machine cache in your settings, you could register it as `"localMachineCache"` (renamed it to stick with common C# coding conventions in the constructor of `SettingsPageViewModel`) and give the parameter that very name

```cs
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<ICacheService>(new CacheService(BlobCache.LocalMachine, "MyAppName"), "localMachineCache");
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<ICacheService>(new CacheService(BlobCache.UserAccount, "MyAppName"), "userAccountCache");
```

```cs
public SettingsPageViewModel(ICacheService localMachineCache)
{
    CacheService = localMachineCache;
}
```

And accordingly if you need both

```cs
public SettingsPageViewModel(ICacheService localMachineCache, ICacheService userAccountCache)
{
    MachineCacheService = localMachineCache;
    UserAccountCacheService = userAccountCache;
}
```

### Edit

Although it is written in the docs, named services don't seem to work the way the documentation states. However, depending on the choice of IoC container it's still possible injecting services by their names.

#### DryIoc

With the `made` parameter of `IContainer.Register` you can specify a factory function to create instances of a specified type. Since Prism puts an IoC abstraction over the framework used, you'll first have to obtain the DryIoc `IContainer` instance

```cs
var container = ((DryIocContainerExtension)containerRegistry).Instance;
```

now you can specify how to create instances of `SettingsPageViewModel` with

```cs
container.Register(Made.Of(
    () => new SettingsPageViewModel(Arg.Of<ICacheService>("LocalMachineCache"))));
```

The string passed to `Arg.Of` is the service key, the service has been registered with and tells `DryIoc` which `ICacheService` to resolve (**please note** that I've used your original name).

#### Unity

With unity there are at least two ways to achieve this. The first one is to obtain an instance via `UnityContainerExtension` (similar to the DryIoc version) and use `RegisterFactory`

```cs
unityContainer.RegisterFactory<SettingsPageViewModel>(
    container => new SettingsPageViewModel(container.Resolve<ICacheService>("LocalMachineCache")));
```

The other option is to add the `DependencyAttribute` to the constructor parameters of the viewmodel

```cs
public SettingsPageViewModel([Unity.Dependency("LocalMachineCache")] ICacheService localMachineCache)
{
    CacheService = localMachineCache;
}
```

Comment: I‘ll have a look at it later today or maybe tomorrow

Comment: @Kerberos It does not seem to work as it should according to the docs. [I've filed an issue](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Documentation/issues/58) in the docs project. Anyway, there are ways to use named services anyway, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done at the time of registration:

[Adapted from the docs](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RequiredServiceType):

```
container.Register<SettingsPageViewModel>(made: Made.Of(() => new SettingsPageViewModel(Arg.Of<ICacheService>("LocalMachineCache"))));
```

Generally, you want to avoid this kind of thing, because the above registration is rather fragile and clunky. Also, I'm just *guessing* that the settings page should get the *LocalMachineCache*, because DryIoc doesn't want to guess, you get an error.

I suggest you revisit your architecture to make it clear who decides who gets which kind of `ICacheService`. If it is the trivial case of a configuration setting, look it up at configuration time and register the appropriate service type (and only that). If it's a setting changed by the user, you should have a repository of service types available and a provider that's injected into the consumers that can give to them the correct instance. That's not the job of the container, anyway.